# Having trouble with my if functions, no matter what the input is, the print for option 2 is displayed

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hey python beginner here, I'm trying to write a paint my number adventure type game but no matter what the user input is the print "your going to get it!" is displayed to the user. But I honestly have no clue where my mess-up in my if functions are. Everything looks correct to me but it still remains the same no matter how I change it up. Any help is appreciated!

```py
# Adventure project

print('A man approachs you with his sword drawn and an angry look spread across his face, what do you do?')
print('1. Run away')
print('2. Punch the man')
fightOrRun = input()

if fightOrRun == '2' or '2.':
    print('Man: "Your going to get it!"')

elif fightOrRun == '1' or '1.':
    print('Man: "Where do you think your going!"')

else:
    print('Not a valid input!')
```